The word "let" as in "without let or hindrance"
There is a legal phrase "without let or hindrance".
The word  "let" seems peculiar,  and actually opposite to the usual meaning.
Looking for the origin of this particular useage.   Is it, perhaps,  a separate word that is only coincidentally the same spelling?   Is it ever used in this sense outside of that specific phrase.?

It's "let" as a noun. Two dictionaries with that example:
AHD let
let (2) noun 1. Something that hinders; an obstacle:
free to investigate without let or hindrance.
It's also in Merriam-Webster:
M-W let
: something that impedes : obstruction
ruled his little world without hindrance or let—
"Let" as that noun has its own etymology:
etymonline let
The link says it's obsolete except in legal contexts.
That makes it a homograph of other senses of "let".

Thank you. It seems it is only used in that particular phrase.

It's used with the same sense in tennis

@AakashM  I'm not quite sure about that. That tennis "let" might be about hindrance, or it might also be about allowance, relating to the verb sense of "let". I didn't find any reference about that.

@JackO'Flaherty /shrug, OED is sure. Sorry, bit terse, it's here, but that's paywalled - although membership of many UK libraries gives access, if that helps
